# Date Time string with AM/PM conversion to DateTime in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I am having trouble converting the strings with `DateTime` information in AM/PM format.
I get the same result for 12:10 AM and 12:10 PM, though these should be different.
Other than 12:xx:xx AM works just fine.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```sql
select 
    parseDateTimeBestEffort('2020-01-01 12:10:00 AM'),
    parseDateTimeBestEffort('2020-01-01 12:10:00 PM')
```

Result:

> 2020-01-01 12:10:00
> 2020-01-01 12:10:00

Comment: it was fixed in version [21.1.2.15](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/whats-new/changelog/#clickhouse-release-v21-1-2-15-stable-2021-01-18).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wrong behavior was fixed starting with ClickHouse version [21.1.2.15](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/whats-new/changelog/#clickhouse-release-v21-1-2-15-stable-2021-01-18).

---

Unfortunately, it is the specificity of the current implementation. Let's check the source code:

[parseDateTimeBestEffort.h](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/5b0b3b455177931b92121cf47590b3053b0cab52/src/IO/parseDateTimeBestEffort.h#L53)

> AM/PM - AM is ignored and PM means: add 12 hours if value is less than 12.

(see [parseDateTimeBestEffort.cpp](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/5b0b3b455177931b92121cf47590b3053b0cab52/src/IO/parseDateTimeBestEffort.cpp#L563))

---

I created the bug [#18402 parseDateTimeBestEffort should not ignore AM abbreviation for 12th hour](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/18402).

---

As a workaround, I would suggest this way:

```sql
SELECT
    str,
    parseDateTimeBestEffort(str) AS dt,
    if((toHour(dt) = 12) AND (str ILIKE '% am'), subtractHours(dt, 12), dt) AS fixed_dt
FROM 
(
    SELECT '2020-02-01 12:10:00 AM' AS str
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2020-02-01 12:10:00 am'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2020-02-01 12:10:00 Am'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2020-02-01 12:10:00 aM'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2020-02-01 12:10:00 PM'
)
ORDER BY fixed_dt

/*
┌─str────────────────────┬──────────────────dt─┬────────────fixed_dt─┐
│ 2020-02-01 12:10:00 AM │ 2020-02-01 12:10:00 │ 2020-02-01 00:10:00 │
│ 2020-02-01 12:10:00 am │ 2020-02-01 12:10:00 │ 2020-02-01 00:10:00 │
│ 2020-02-01 12:10:00 Am │ 2020-02-01 12:10:00 │ 2020-02-01 00:10:00 │
│ 2020-02-01 12:10:00 aM │ 2020-02-01 12:10:00 │ 2020-02-01 00:10:00 │
│ 2020-02-01 12:10:00 PM │ 2020-02-01 12:10:00 │ 2020-02-01 12:10:00 │
└────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘

*/
```